# WooCommerce product prices not showing up correctly

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

For my website I simply wanted to display products with prices below. This was all working fine until I opened up the website yesterday and every price on the website was set to **0,00$** , instead of it's regular **$9,95**.

Does or did anyone have the same problem? Please help :)

Comment: Any more information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you install any new plugin? 
If so, try to deactivate that plugin first.

What version of WooCommerce are you using?
If you are using an outdated one, try updating it to the latest version.

Can you try to add a dummy product and add a price on it? If the price still did not display try to deactivate and reactivate the woocommerce plugin.

Comment: Care to explain the reason behind the downvote please?